# AWS Blue-Green deployments with Fargate and CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, amazon-elb, blue-green-deployment

It is possible with AWS to have Blue-Green deployments for your ECS Fargate instances under a load balancer. This is achieved through the AWS CodeDeploy service.

However, when configuring CodeDeploy, you provide load balancer's listeners for production traffic and listeners for testing traffic. **There is no way to specify listeners' routing rules.** This means when using Blue-Green deployments I can not reuse the same load balancer with same listeners for different projects.

*Is there a somewhat solution or workaround for this problem?* I would like to use Blue-Green deployments at the same time using only one loadbalancer for all my projects.